# Way to sync users between multiple databases in nodejs - mongodb app

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm working on a nodejs app, which can have users using multiple languages. So my design is creating `lang1.example.com` and `lang2.example.com` sites for respective languages. So that it's easy to manage each language with its own database.

At the same time, I don't want users to create different accounts for each language - so that they can keep using same credentials across the different domains.

To do this, I'm planning to sync the credentials in users collection across all the databases. This syncing will happen whenever an user creates an account Or user changes credentials(password, email, etc.).
The other fields in the users collection will not be synced - such as user followers, user's language specific activities.

However, I'm not feeling confident about above design approach since it will involve a lot of syncing between the databases.

What could be an alternate solution so that I can avoid such syncing ?

Comment: Why would you use different databases?  You can have separate presentation layers that all share the same database.  It seems to me you've made a problem that doesn't need to exist.

Comment: just add a an attribute  lang in each doc of you collection  and then filter by this lang

Comment: @jfriend00 I sort of cannot rely on presentation layer. The site content for each language is going to be different. Since the content is different, I don't want all content to live in a single database with a lot of 'lang' flags everywhere.

Comment: Then, put the common data in one database that all languages use and put the language specific content in separate database.  I don't see why you're creating a synchronization need at all.  There's no rule that each language has to use only one database.  For example, I would think you would want all user registrations in one database, regardless of language.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. I realized that syncing is not at all a good choice. I'm going with the approach to do a single database for all the users. And language specific database for the content.